# GridLayout scaling animation in Java

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm coding a Sudoku game using Java and I want to animate the new game action as follows:

- Once the user clicks start game, each element starts appearing sequentially from top left corner to bottom right corner.
- The animations should start with a 100ms delay from each other, not all at the same time. Like from 60% to 100% and then finish the animation for each element.

My code to load the puzzle model into a JPanel is:

```
    public void newSudoku(SudokuBoard puzzle){
    this.puzzle = puzzle;
    this.myimages = new ImageButton(this.puzzle);
    for (int i=0;i<ROWS*COLUMNS;i++)
    {
            int row = i / ROWS;
            int column = i % ROWS;
            this.mylabels[row][column] = new JLabel(myimages.getImageMatrix()[row][column]);
            this.add(this.mylabels[row][column]);
    }
}
```

puzzle Object has the numbers from 1 to 300 corresponding to the images, so it's used when I create ImageButton myimages. "this" is my custom JPanel with a 3*3 GridLayout.

They way it is, it's fully loaded in one run so I'm unable to animate it. I don't need a movement animation so that reduces the complexity of the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't need a movement animation so that reduces the complexity of the task.

So one way could be to add all the components to the panel as you are currently doing, except you make all the components invisible.

Then when you click the "Start" button you use a `Swing Timer` to start the animation process. Every time the Timer event fires you make the next components visible. When the last component is visible you stop the `Timer`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and examples.